# UWP Visual Studio 2017 ObservableCollection sorting

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection, visual-studio-2017

I am a having a little trouble trying to find a way to sort an observable collection. I am currently trying to test this process by using an event from a button that is pressed to change in realtime a listview showing the observable collection and I understand that I cannot use the "Sort" command but I am able to get this accomplished by using the "OrderBy" command. My code currently is as follows:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    ObservableCollection<DataType> collection = new ObservableCollection<DataType>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        setupCollection();
    }

    public void setupCollection()
    {
        collection.Add(new DataType { times = "08:30" });
        collection.Add(new DataType { times = "00:30" });
        collection.Add(new DataType { times = "12:30" });
        collection.Add(new DataType { times = "23:30" });
        collection.Add(new DataType { times = "18:30" });
        collection.Add(new DataType { times = "15:30" });
        collection.Add(new DataType { times = "06:30" });
        collection.Add(new DataType { times = "05:30" });
        collection.Add(new DataType { times = "14:00" });
        collection.Add(new DataType { times = "12:00" });
        listview.ItemsSource = collection;
    }

    public class DataType
    {
        public string times { get; set; }
    }

    private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        collection = new ObservableCollection<DataType>(from i in DataType orderby i.times select i);
        //collection.OrderBy(i.DataType > i.times);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to fix my code so that I can order the items in it?

Comment: In what way can you not get OrderBy to work?

Comment: Note that in WPF, this would be trivial to accomplish using `CollectionViewSource`. For ideas about accomplishing similar in UWP, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915276/uwp-observablecollection-sorting-and-grouping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is: that you are searching in the class Datatype, you need to search in the collection so you can take the values and put them in order... Here is the solution:

```
collection = new ObservableCollection<DataType>(
    from i in collection orderby i.times select i);
```

That worked for me.
Hope for you too.

Answer (score 0):

simple and easy way to do that:

```
ConceptItems = new ObservableCollection<DataConcept>(ConceptItems.OrderBy(i => i.DateColumn));
```